# How to upload a prepared html page on Google sites?

Tags: google, html, page, uploading

In order to create an html page using Google sites, there are some tools and templates in the Google sites itself; however, I did not find an option for uploading an html page (site) that has been created already (outside of Google sites).

Is there any possibility for this purpose ?

I tested `Embed` option, but it is not what I want, as the embedded html will cover only a part the screen ...

**P.S.** This html page is not a part of website, but it is a whole of website. (The website is a single html page.)

Answer (score 4):

The only way to edit a site created with Google Sites is through the Google Sites editor.   It is not possible to upload an HTML file or even to edit the HTML of the page the editor creates for you.  See [How do I use HTML in new google site editor? - Sites Community](https://support.google.com/sites/thread/6100429?hl=en):

> The new version of Google Sites does not offer HTML editing and never will as the whole idea of new Google Sites is to make a system where HTML editing it not needed.

If you have created your site as an HTML page, you will want to find hosting for it that is not based on Google Sites.  Pretty much any shared hosting service will do what you want.  You will get FTP access to be able to upload your HTML file.   See [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)